# Custom build environment/target libraries

Tags: c++, linux, build, glibc, libtool

I want to build an application that will be **compatible with, say, Debian Lenny** (libc, postgres, oracle and other libs) **on a different Debian/Ubuntu release**.
Is this possible? If so, where can I read how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [open build service](http://openbuildservice.org/) for this. Create the Debian package description files for it (you can add also rpm spec files), select the target distributions and you will get it built on each platform and also get a specific download repository for each platform. Your package will be rebuilt automatically when needed as well. You can install your own instance of the service if you need to host proprietary code.

If you want a multiplatform binary, you may want to build it against a LSB chroot:

http://ftp.linux-foundation.org/pub/lsb/impl

And bundle any library that is not part of it. The LSB has tools to then check your app for compliance. Their website is down right now, but it should be here: http://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/check-your-app